# how do i use 4 digit numbers in vb

Tags: vb.net

I need to count from `0 - 9999` in VB. How can I make the format `0000 - 9999`, so that the output is:

```
0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, .......
```

I used the following code

```
Dim p4num As Integer = 0
Dim p3num As Integer = 0
Dim p2num As Integer = 0
Dim p1num As Integer = 0

p4num += 1
If p4num = 10 Then
    p4num = 0
    p3num += 1
    If p3num = 10 Then
        p3num = 0
        p2num += 1
        If p2num = 10 Then
            p2num = 0
            p1num += 1
        End If
    End If
End If
```

but I would do it in another way. Any idea?

Comment: there, I re-edit my post sir Richard Schneider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guide

```
Dim numbers As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, 9999).ToArray()
'object j = string.Join(", ", numbers);
For Each item As var In numbers
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString("#0000"))
Next
```

Comment: This looks like C# not VB!

Answer (score 3):

The `ToString()` may help.  How about

```
myint.ToString("0000")
```

or

```
myint.ToString("D4");
```

Comment: My post was how to format an integer into a 4 digit string.  @Mr47 provided the total solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
For i as integer = 0 to 9999
     Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString("0000"))
next
```

Untested code, but should work...

Comment: Am I gonna use the Debug.WritLine(i.ToString("0000")) too?

Comment: That's just an example way to output the number. The important part is the `.ToString("0000")`. You could write to a file or to the console or to...

Comment: I already have the right answer, `p1num.ToString("D4")` thanks anyway :)